# SQL Divide a string when a comma appears and join it back in reverse order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column which has data in this way,

**Table1**

**FullName**

```
Lastname1, Firstname1

Lastname2, Firstname2

Lastname3, Firstname3
```

I want the result to be,

```
Firstname1 Lastname1

Firstname2 Lastname2

Firstname3 Lastname3
```

When I use this query

```
SELECT (substring(Name,charindex(',',Name)+1 ,250)+ SUBSTRING(Name,0, CHARINDEX(',',Name))) from @table1
```

the result I am getting is

Firstname1 ...

Firstname2 ...

Firstname3 ...

Please help

Comment: Do you just want all fields in your table concatenated thusly?  Or is there some field you'd use to determine which rows belong together?

Comment: What is wrong with your results?

Comment: Apart from adding an extra space, this basically seems to work? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/25191

Comment: Looks to me like you just need to add a space between the two substrings.

Comment: Are you using something to display that puts `...` in when the column is to wide??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fc0f/16/0

```
Select 
right(name,len(name)-charindex(', ',name)) + ' ' +
left(name,charindex(', ',name)-1)
from @table1;
```

Comment: This query is giving me results in this fashion...

     Lasttname1

     Lastnmame2


There are spaces for first name... but first name is not appearing...

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying... this worked fine... I am just wondering... why it did not work the first time... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Provided name doesn't contain a . You can use

```
parsename ( replace ( name, ',','.'),1) + ' ' + parsename ( replace ( name, ',','.'),2)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying... but the result is still the same... it has firstname and lastname is replaced with periods...

Comment: Odd seems to work for me [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c40c/3/0) Anyway you have a couple of working solutions already.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(name,len(name)-CHARINDEX(',',name,0))+' '+LEFT(name,CHARINDEX(',',name,0)-1),name,CHARINDEX(',',name,0)
from @table1
```

Comment: The error I got when I executed this query is




Must declare the scalar variable "@T".